# c# VSTO plugin for Outlook, that would download new messages when mailbox is in header only mode

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

I have a mailbox that can only operate in header only mode for Outlook. Header mode sucks to use day-to-day. What I want to do is set Outlook to header only mode for the entire mailbox, BUT automatically download full-items for all newly arrived messages.

I grabbed some code from MS website, but I cannot find a method on the mailitem object that does: "Download the rest of this message now" for that new mail item. Here is what I have so far, below. I think the simplest approach is to check for the download state property (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/mailitem-downloadstate-property-outlook) if it is not downloaded, then "Download teh rest of this message now".

All of this would happen with a new mail item event. I am NOT a programmer. I know nothing. Any suggestions are much appreciated.

```
public partial class ThisAddIn   {
    Outlook.NameSpace outlookNameSpace;
    Outlook.MAPIFolder inbox;
    Outlook.Items items;

    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        outlookNameSpace = this.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        inbox = outlookNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.
                OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

        items = inbox.Items;
        items.ItemAdd +=
            new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(items_ItemAdd);
    }

    void items_ItemAdd(object Item)
    {
        //CHECK IF MAIL IS HEADER-ONLY. IF IT IS, DOWNLOAD FULL ITEM.


        }

    #region VSTO generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InternalStartup()
    {
        this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
        this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The message will be downloaded on demand when you touch it with the Outlook Object Model.